# remove special characters with regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have this input string: `'- - Adele Gislan - Web Developer - - - '`
 and the expected output is this string: `Adele Gislan - Web Developer`

I use this regular expression

```
$urli='- - Adele Gislan - Web Developer - - - ';
$urli = preg_replace("/\-[[:space:]]+$/","",$urli);
$urli = preg_replace("/\-+$/","",$urli);
```

But this remove special character "-" or "- " only one time.

I try this

```
$urli = rtrim($urli, '-');
$urli = ltrim($urli, '-');
```

but isnt ideal

Comment: Your `rtrim`/`ltrim` attempt was on the right track. But you want to remove spaces and dashes in unison; so `trim($str, "- ")` for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the space and `-` symbol inside a character class,

```
^[ -]+|[ -]+$
```

Just replace the matched characters with an empty string.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cN4tF8/4)

PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$mystring = "- - Adele Gislan - Web Developer - - - ";
echo preg_replace('~^[ -]+|[ -]+$~', '', $mystring);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Adele Gislan - Web Developer
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[ -]+` Matches one or more space or `-` characters.
- `|` Logical OR operator which is usually used to combine two regexes.
- `[ -]+` Matches one or more space or `-` characters.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

To get from:

```
 - - Adele Gislan - Web Developer - - -
```

to

```
Adele Gislan - Web Developer
```

use:

```
[ -]{4,}
```

php-preg:

```
'/[ -]{4,}/m'
```

---

Alternatively you could use:

```
(?: *-+ *){2,}
```

php-preg:

```
'/(?: *-+ *){2,}/m'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to trim leading and trailing dashes and spaces, there's no need to use regular expressions. You could use one call to `trim`:

```
echo trim($urli, '- ');
```

The second argument is a list of characters to be removed.

Output:

```
Adele Gislan - Web Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be extra-*greedy* and simply match word bounds:

```php
$str = ' - - Adele Gislan - Web Developer - - -';
$str = preg_replace('/.*?(\b.+\b).*/', '$1', $str);
```

[**» fiddle**](http://ideone.com/Gui2dq) 
[**» regex explanation**](http://regex101.com/r/iZ4lP2/1)